# Youtube iframe loop only loops 2 times

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

So I know this is really basic stuff, but I cannot seem to get it right.
This is my Iframe

```html
<iframe id="bg" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S4L8T2kFFck?version=3&end=105&disablekb=0&enablejsapi=1&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&version=3&playlist=S4L8T2kFFck" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

To hightlight it this is the imortant part:

```
S4L8T2kFFck?version=3&end=105&disablekb=0&enablejsapi=1&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&version=3&playlist=S4L8T2kFFck
```

So the problem is that when I play it it runs 2 times and then stops, I have included the version 3 , loop, and the playlist. 
Any suggestions on a fix?

Thanks in advance=)

Comment: error at the youtube url

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper is there any way you could tell me where, because I really cannot see it

Answer (score 1):

Youtube has a pretty robust fake view algorythm to keep people from abusing the ads. you won't get far with that.

Refer to [this link](http://www.umeraslam.com/youtube-views-script-tutorial/) for more information